# PHP showing source code although web server is on and working fine

Tags: php

i have 3 files.
I have a html file, having a simple forum that has login and password.
On entering, it should run a php script called display.php and take me to a page showing user's details.

however it just prints the source code of display.php!
The server works fine as my other php files are working properly!!

PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: Are you using http://localhost ?

Comment: still not working!!

Comment: yeah i am using localhost!!

Comment: My other php files seems to work fine, just this isn't!

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the source of display.php?

Comment: If your other .php files are interpreted properly, I assume it must be something like a malformed or missing `<?php` opening tag.

Comment: have u used <?php or <? as tag on the beginning of your php code?

Comment: sorry guys, my bad!!! I was using atom's inbuilt html viewer to display the html file on the browser, instead of the actual path to the file. Seems to be the problem!